# How to set the external monitor as the default Monitor when dualmonitor is enabled?

Tags: 10.10, multiple-monitors, ati

I have an ATI radeon hd 2600 in my Laptop. I connected a 23" external monitor via VGA. But when I enable dualmonitor in System-Preferences-Monitors the internal monitor of my laptop is set as the default monitor. Is there a way to change the default monitor to the external monitor without disabling the internal monitor?

Answer (score 1):

I think a `xrandr --output VGA-0 --primary` did it...

Comment: is that permanent or session only?